# Callback method after multiple asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Is there a way to wait for multiple API calls to respond before executing a line code ?

Usually, I use :

```
APIService.call(parameter).then(function(response) {
   // Do things
   callBack();
});
```

And this works fine, `callBack()` is executed after the the `APIService.call()`'s answer.

But let's say I have 3 different API calls like this :

```
$scope.var1 = APIService.call1(parameter)
$scope.var2 = APIService.call2(parameter)
$scope.var3 = APIService.call3(parameter)
```

And I want my callback to be called after the 3 calls answered, meaning after the longest one answers.
How could I do that ?
I don't want to make nested `then` because I want my 3 calls to keep being called asynchronously.

Is this doable ?

Comment: [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: @George comment ;)

Comment: you can save your response of each call in a variable and once the three variable set you can execute the final callback function.

Comment: Angular handles promises with `$q`, so use `$q.all()` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using AngularJS, you can use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Do something like:

```
var promises = [];

promises.push(APIService.call1(parameter));
promises.push(APIService.call2(parameter));
promises.push(APIService.call3(parameter));

$q.all(promises).then(function (values) {
    // you can access the response from each promise
    $scope.var1 = values[0];
    $scope.var2 = values[1];
    $scope.var3 = values[2];
    doSomething();
})
```

Comment: I didn't even see this question was tagged as angularJS, this would be the right way to go.

Comment: I edited a bit the question, can I make an assignation from the answer of each call inside the push method ? Something like `promises.push($scope.var = APIService.call1(parameter));`

Comment: @Ellone try doing something like: `promises.push(APIService.call1(parameter).then(function (response) {
 $scope.var = response; 
}));`

Comment: @Ellone note that when you are using $q.all you have access to the "answer" of each response in the parameter passed to the `.then` function of `$q.all`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $q.all() method, simply pass it an array of promises you want to resolve, what this does is it takes the array of promises and returns a single promise which will resolve once all the original promises have been resolved.

```
$q.all([
  APIService.call1(parameter),
  APIService.call2(parameter),
  APIService.call3(parameter),
]).then(function(data) {

   //TODO: something...
});
```